# Scrollable text over image HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Currently I can not find a solution that is responsive and scrollable to put text on an image. I need the height to be flexible and the width at 100%. I tried to use position:relative; and css background images with no luck. When I use position: relative; there is a space at the top of the image and the only way to delete it is negative margins which I think is not sustainable it there are multiple posts. css backgrounds does not show the full image unless you set dimensions and when is responsive you cant set dimensions. I dont think I can use position absolute because it would not scroll. so I dont not know what to use.

I have this **HTML** code here:

```
<div class="post">
    <span><a>Posted By Adam</a></span>
    <img width="100%" src="uimg/adam-levine-600.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: add `height:auto;` to the image?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by scrollable, maybe you could provide a link to your site or a fiddle example. `position: absolute;` seems to work OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/p3bes5xq/

Comment: `position:absolute` the image and `top:0` You should post a codepen so we can see the problem

Comment: @ryan I have a top menu with the position set as fixed and if i do position absolute the Posted by adam part goes over the menu as the picture its attatched to goes under http://s3.postimg.org/4lnkz25gj/Screen_Shot_2015_09_09_at_11_34_36_PM.png

Comment: @Eric you need to provide a complete example then ... as you can see in a minimal environment `position: absolute;` will work.

Comment: @ryan yes that is true Thank you for trying

Comment: @Eric, why don't you just add a spacer? http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/p3bes5xq/

Comment: I added a z index from your code and it worked! @ryan thanks!

Comment: @Eric, that is great! I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` and add a spacer for the nav:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/p3bes5xq/

```css
.nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #21A7F0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.spacer {
  height: 105px;
}
.post span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
}
.post img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">nav bar</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="post"> <span><a>Posted By Adam</a></span>

  <img src="//fillmurray.com/880/450" />
</div>
<div class="post"> <span><a>Posted By Adam</a></span>

  <img src="//fillmurray.com/880/260" />
</div>
<div class="post"> <span><a>Posted By Adam</a></span>

  <img src="//fillmurray.com/880/194" />
</div>
```